# Javascript problems on my site. Can't find the error

Tags: javascript, opencart

Something just happened to my site, and I can't really get my error logs to show any error. It's working perfectly in Firefox so I can't really find the error with firebug. When I analyze the site in Chrome I can't see any errors either, but the javascripts isn't running correctly at all.

When I try to add products to the shopping nothing really happens in Chrome, but when I press "Check Cart" all the products are there. When I press delete nothing happens either, but if I update the site the products are deleted just as they're supposed to.

BUT when I add some products, and then press "Check Card" I get this error message (can't mark the text so unfortunately it's in image mode):
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0psWO.jpg)

How can I find the error on this one?

My site is at www nosmoke se and I'm using Open Cart 1.5.4.1 if anyone's wondering.

Comment: There are some comments in your json: `<!--Begin Attracta Include...`. You should probably remove them from the source code. And, BTW, you can copy text from error message by simply pressing `Ctrl+C`.

Answer (score 1):

And the end of the JSON being sent, there is an HTML comment that begins with `<!--`

Find out where that is coming from and get rid of it.

It looks like there is also a script tag there at the bottom that shouldnt' be there.

Comment: I can't find it anywhere :(

I added a few SEO-things from something called Attracta which is a SEO-tool provided by my host company. So I haven't really changed in the code.

Comment: Considering that the comment begins with `<!--Begin Attracta Include` as @llia pointed out, it sounds like Attracta is being interjected into everything that your web server is sending out.  That is way behind my ability to help with, though on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ you might be able to find some help.

Comment: @JaozaMedia How did you add that 'tool'? Did you copy and paste JS into your site? That's an HTML comment and will cause compile errors from the JS interpreter.

Comment: @Chris -- It looks like he enabled something on his hosting service that started to auto-inject adds (or some other forced content) onto all of his pages and that it is also affecting his JSON stream.

Answer (score 1):

Attracta added features can cause issues with AJAX requests on certain sites (such as OpenCart). In the end, you need to request for Attracta to have it disabled but that can take from a few hours to a few days.

To remove the Attracta code immediately you will need to delete the .fastinclude file from the 'web root' (document root) of your website.

To delete this file:
1. Log into your account 'File Manager'
2. Choose the 'Web Root (public_html/www)' option and ensure 'Show Hidden Files (dotfiles)' is ticked if using a GUI.
3. Select the file named '.fastinclude' and Delete

After deleting this file, the app will be removed instantly.